# Jenkins pipeline: checkout explicit git commit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to be able to say something like:

```
git branch: commitHash, credentialsId: credentialsId, url: url
```

The usecase: I'm doing parallel build and test runs on different platforms, and want to ensure each gets the same code. It is C++, and we build on separate platforms as well as building on them.

If I do the above, it fails - the underlying code assumes the given branch actually is a branch, or you get something like:

```
[Linux64 Build]  > git rev-parse origin/e4b6c976a0a986c348a211579f1e8fd32cf29567^{commit} # timeout=10
[Pipeline] [Linux64 Build] }
[Pipeline] [Linux64 Build] // dir
[Pipeline] [Linux64 Build] }
[Pipeline] [Linux64 Build] // node
[Pipeline] [Linux64 Build] }
[Linux64 Build] Failed in branch Linux64 Build
```

I've seen variations on this question asked before, although no actual answers - just suggestions like to stash the source code instead, etc. Not really what I'm after.

The documentation suggests it ought to be possible to give explicit commit hashes, possibly using branches instead, but I can't work out the syntax and can't find any examples. When I do it, I get the master branch, I think - in our setup, master does not work.

So far, the only solution I've found has been to checkout the branch and then explicitly call git to get the commit:

```
                git branch: branch, credentialsId: credentialsId, url: url
                sh 'git checkout ' + commitHash
```

(where branch is the branch I originally got the hash for at the top of the job. It works but is not the neatest.

Anybody got a better way?

Comment: See comments of 2017-07-12 and 2017-07-13 in [JENKINS-31826] (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31826)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use a [general scm](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#checkout-general-scm) step

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: commitHash ]],
     userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'http://git-server/user/repository.git']]])
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to add the credentialsId bit?

Comment: I'm relying on the ssh key of the Jenkins user

Comment: I think I managed to work it out - not least I've just noticed there is a snippet "editor" for this. It would be something like:

    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: commitHash ]],
         userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: credentialsId, url: 'http://git-server/user/repository.git']]])

Comment: Well, this works provided a clone happened previously.  Otherwise, if the commit ID isn't in the refspec it won't be found.  So, if it is a HEAD for tag or branch, all is good.  If not, it fails

Comment: @PeterKahn This seems to work fine for me, except when I use `CloneOptions`, such as `extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: true]]`. To workaround, I am now passing this parameter conditionally by checking if `branch` refers to a SHA-1 hash (`branch.matches('^[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$')`).

Comment: Coming here after a long time, but wanted to update that if you need to pass `CloneOption` with `shallow: true` to checkout a commit SHA or tag, you can use `honorRefspec: true` and `noTags: false` along with setting `refspec: <sha or tag>` under `userRemoteConfigs`

Answer (score 15):

Yuri G's example didn't work for me when jenkins lacked a workspace due to initial checkout.  The following works in this case.  I don't understand why they are all that different.

```
    def commitId = "<insert sha here>"

    checkout ( [$class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: [[name: commitId ]],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[
            credentialsId: 'deploy key for your repo', 
            url: 'repo url']]])
```

Comment: I've been using:

                    steps.checkout([$class           : 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: hash]],
                              userRemoteConfigs: [[url: url, credentialsId: 'key of credentials']]])

Comment: that's pretty much the same as I've got.  I just split out the lines and use a different order.  The order shouldn't matter

Comment: The difference between ours and Yuri is the cred Id - that's probably it.  Public repo vs private.  Silly me

Answer (score -1):

To checkout a specific hash from your repository, in Jenkins pipeline, you can do something like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  options {
      timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
  }
  environment {
    // Jenkins credentials for git auth
    SOURCECODE_JENKINS_CREDENTIAL_ID = 'sourcecode-credential'
    // URL of the repo
    SOURCE_CODE_URL = 'https://sourcecode.com/repo.git'
    // branch
    RELEASE_BRANCH = 'dev'
    // hash
    GIT_HASH = 'your_hash'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Git') {
      agent any
      steps {
        sleep(5)
        
       // Clean dir
        deleteDir()
        
        // Checkout branch
        git branch: "$RELEASE_BRANCH", credentialsId: "$SOURCECODE_JENKINS_CREDENTIAL_ID" , url: "$SOURCE_CODE_URL"
        
    // Checkout hash
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "$SOURCECODE_JENKINS_CREDENTIAL_ID", usernameVariable: 'GIT_USER', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASS')]) {
          sh "git checkout '$GIT_HASH'"
        }  
      }
    }
  }
}
```