# Jenkins git plugin query

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

With Jenkins git plugin, you have options for branch, url and credentials. How do I pass the revision (SHA1), in order to checkout a particular revision of the branch?
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Thanks.

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611673/jenkins-pipeline-checkout-explicit-git-commit. This worked using checkout.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't. The plugin will always fetch and check out *references*, not commits.

Fetching specific commits by SHA1 is a relatively new feature (see [Retrieve specific commit from a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/retrieve-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository/24084746)); it is not even support by all repository servers.

If you're *sure* that the SHA1 exists on the branch that has been fetched, then you're free to `git reset` the working copy in a build step. However, you'd mess with a git clone that's maintained by the git plugin -- so I recommend to take care of the entire clone/fetch/checkout step yourself, not using the git plugin.