# Trigger a Jenkins build for a branch and a commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 Jenkins (scripted) pipelines: main and e2e. My flow is: run the main pipeline which has a stage that triggers the e2e pipeline

```
stage('Trigger e2e') {
  build(
    job: 'e2e/my-repo/master',
    propagate: false,
    wait: false
  )
}
```

The problem here is that the e2e pipeline always checks out the latest master, which might cause inconsistency. I want to check out the same revision as the main pipeline (that triggered it).

Is there a way to trigger a specific revision within a pipeline?

One solution I have found is to pass the revision as a parameter to the e2e pipeline and then do `checkout scm` for that revision. But is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One solution I have found is to pass the revision as a parameter to the e2e pipeline and then do checkout scm for that revision. But is there any other way to achieve it?

Not that I know of: as explained in "[Jenkins pipeline: checkout explicit git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44979064/6309)", you need a parameter for a [`checkout` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#checkout-general-scm) to be able to set your Jenkins workspace with the right version of the code.