# How can I capture the commit the Jenkinsfile is pulled from and only checkout that revision?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I can see at the top of my Jenkinsfile the hash that is being used for the build:

```
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 57e5d9...
```

The build then goes through a number of steps where it needs to checkout out the code at the beginning of each K8's pod being spun up. We're using a shallow clone due to the size of the repo, but a problem occurs when a new commit is pushed to the branch mid-run.

We're using Git commit statuses to post back the status of the build. So on the first checkout (no new change has been pushed), the shallow clone fetches the HEAD and that's the commit we're posting to. When the phase is complete, it does it again. If a new commit is pushed mid-phase, the next clone/fetch now retrieves a different commit hash (the new change) since it's fetching by *branch*. I'd like to fetch by *hash* to force it to only keep cloning the specific hash.

```
git checkout -f 57e5d9
returned status code 128
fatal: reference 57e5d9 is not a tree
```

This is a multi-branch pipeline, and I have read that `env.GIT_COMMIT` is available, but it only seems to be available after first running the `GitSCM` checkout. Somehow the master (?) node knows the commit hash at the beginning, is that available in the runners immediately?

I know I can change the [checkout to point to a specific ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43613408/3220769), but I don't know how to get that `ref` at runtime.